# How to bring a background job started in a function to the foreground

Tags: bash, jobs

I have this simple bash function:

```bash
function sb() {
    # Starts a process in the background, suppressing any stdout / stderr output.
    $* >/dev/null 2>&1 &
}
```

I can use it to start some process in the background, for example: `sb ping google.com`, and when I type `jobs`, I can see the job and its id, and I can use `fg <id>` to bring it to the foreground. But if I pass an alias to this function, for example the alias `alias ping-google="ping google.com"` I can't see it in the jobs list. Why? Are there any other way to find its id and bring it to the foreground?

Comment: What does 'pass an alias to this function' mean?

Comment: I mean running`sb ping-google`, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html:

> Aliases are expanded when a command is read, not when it is executed. Therefore, an alias definition appearing on the same line as another command does not take effect until the next line of input is read. [...] This behavior is also an issue when functions are executed. Aliases are expanded when a function definition is read, not when the function is executed, because a function definition is itself a command. As a consequence, aliases defined in a function are not available until after that function is executed. To be safe, always put alias definitions on a separate line, and do not use alias in compound commands. For almost every purpose, shell functions are preferred over aliases.

Comment: Thanks, but my aliases definitions are read before the function definitions are read. The command is successfully started in the background. This can easily be verified by not suppressing output in the function.

Comment: That's exactly the problem: aliases are read but not expanded until the function call (not the function definition) is read. Therefore what runs is not `ping google.com` but nothing (i.e. `> /dev/null 2>&1` not `ping google.com > /dev/null 2>&1`). I also tried to verify as you say by removing `> /dev/null`, but I don't see it working it even returns `ping-google: command not found`

Comment: So basically, in order of execution, there goes: 1) alias declaration (not expansion) 2) function definition 3) sb function execution with "ping-google" as first argument (i.e. not yet known as an alias, same as `commandincorrect > /dev/null 2>&1` 4) alias expansion (too late)

Comment: You are right. I got fooled by the fact that the actual alias I'm defining ("jupyter") existed as a valid command beforehand, so I didn't get the "command not found".